Exclude keyof interface of just function based on function return type
I have the following interface:
interface MyInterface {
  GetChocolate: () => string;
  GetVanilla: () => number;
  SetChocolate: () => number;
  SetVanilla: () => string;
} 

The interface is only made up of function types. I have a function that takes in a keyof MyInterface and does something with it (doesn't matter what). However, I only want the function to accept keys where the return type is string. I have something like this:
type KeysReturnStrings<K extends keyof MyInterface> = ReturnType<MyInterface[K]> extends string ? K : never;

This works great when I only pass in one key:
type Test1 = KeysReturnStrings<"GetChocolate">; // "GetChocolate"
type Test2 = KeysReturnStrings<"SetChocolate">; // never

But this does not work when I pass in keyof MyInterface:
type Test3 = KeysReturnStrings<keyof MyInterface>; // never

The type of Test3 when I want it to be "GetChocolate" | "SetVanilla".
I can create a different generic type that filters the keys based on if they contain the work "Get":
type KeysNoGet<K extends keyof MyInterface> = K extends `Get${string}` ? never : K;
type Test4 = KeysNoGet<keyof MyInterface>; // "SetChocolate" | "SetVanilla"

I just do not understand why Test4 works but Test3 doesn't. My only guess is that the issue is to do with passing keyof MyInterface into ReturnType<MyInterface[K]> as this creates a union of the return types of that object (string | number) which obviously do not extend type string. But then keyof MyInterface is a union regardless so it shouldn't be able to extend Get${string} either.
Is there a utility type or a another generic type that can exclude these keys from the union type?

•  KeysReturnStrings<"GetChocolate">; // string no, not string. Please [edit]. • Your KeysReturnStrings<K> does not distribute over unions in K. There are ways to make it do so, such as distributive conditional types which is why KeysNoGet works. You can wrap your type in a distributive conditional type as shown in this playground link to fix it (among other ways). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes, thank you! That's perfect and thank you for the edit

You want KeysReturnStrings<K> to distribute over unions in K, so that KeysReturnStrings<K1 | K2 | K3> is equivalent to KeysReturnStrings<K1> | KeysReturnStrings<K2> | KeysReturnStrings<K3>. But your definition does not do so, and you get unexpected results.
There are a few ways to get type functions to distribute over unions; one of them is to use a distributive conditional type where the type you check is a generic type parameter corresponding to the union you want to distribute over. A type of the form type F<T> = T extends U ? X<T> : Y<T> will distribute over unions in T.  Your KeysNoGet<K> is of that form, so that's why it behaves as you expect.
So we can wrap your definition of KeysReturnStrings<K> in a "no-op" distributive conditional type, which always takes the true branch. We're only using it for its distributive property, not for any sort of conditional type check:
type KeysReturnStrings<K extends keyof MyInterface> = K extends unknown ?
  ReturnType<MyInterface[K]> extends string ? K : never
  : never;

Now you get the behavior you expect:
type Test1 = KeysReturnStrings<"GetChocolate">;
//   ^? type Test1 = "GetChocolate"
type Test2 = KeysReturnStrings<"SetChocolate">;
//   ^? type Test2 = never
type Test3 = KeysReturnStrings<keyof MyInterface>;
//   ^? type Test3 = "GetChocolate" | "SetVanilla"

Playground link to code
